# How to access an Object property's name?

Tags: javascript

I am just wondering how can i get the property names from a js object. for example, in this case, how can i get "Athlete", "muscle-soreness" and "sleep-quality" ?

```
{
    "athlete": [
        "Jamie Anderson"
    ],
    "muscle-soreness": [
        "5"
    ],
    "sleep-quality": [
        "5"
    ]
}
```

Comment: objName.athlete ?

Comment: First things first, what is [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), after reading that, see [how to access properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Object.keys()` function:

```
var obj = {
    "athlete": [
        "Jamie Anderson",
    ],
    "muscle-soreness": [
        "5",
    ],
    "sleep-quality": [
        "5",
    ]
}

console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

Answer (score -1):

Import it

```
var data = require('your_file_name.json')
```

Access it

```
data["athlete"]
```

Comment: The question is asking how to find the names of the properties the object has. It isn't asking how to get the value if you already know what the property name is.

Comment: sorry i understood it wrongly. by "How to access an Object property's name"  i thought he is facing problem to import json from file and access it.

Answer (score -1):

You can access it like a normal object by `obj.propertyname` or by array access, `obj['fieldname']`.

See snippet below to illustrate multiple ways to parse the data.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{\
"athlete": [\
    "Jamie Anderson"\
],\
"muscle-soreness": [\
    "5"\
],\
"sleep-quality": [\
    "5"\
]\
}');
console.log(obj['athlete']);

console.log(obj.athlete);

console.log(obj['muscle-soreness']);

for(key in obj) {
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var values = obj[key];
      if(Array.isArray(values)) {
          console.log(key, obj[key].join(','));
      }
      else {
          console.log(key, obj[key]);
      }
   }
}
```